# -nan(ind) и nan

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    float cnst, div;
    const int a = 4, b = 5;
    float arr[a][b]{
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
    {3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
    {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    };

    for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
        if (arr[k][k] != 1) {
            div = arr[k][k];
            for (int h = k; h < b; h++) {
                arr[k][h] /= div;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            if (i == k)
                continue;
            cnst = -arr[i][k];
            for (int j = k; j < b; j++) {
                arr[i][j] += arr[k][j] * cnst;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Написал некий фрагмент кода (вообще пишу решение СЛАУ методом Гаусса), при данных значениях а и b, когда k >= 2 возникает ошибка -nan(ind) и nan (когда как, в зависимости от значений). Помогите исправить. И еще, после каких вычислений или из-за чего в С++ появляется значение -0? Спасибо!)

Comment: Если у вас чисто практическая задача, то для начала попробуйте заменить `float` на `double`

Comment: Скорее всего где-то вы делите на 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас после итерации `k = 1` на диагонали появляются нулевые элементы. На следующей итерации по `k` в первом цикле происходит деление на `0` со всеми вытекающими.

При реализации "метода Гаусса" во всех его проявлениях надо помнить о возможности возникновения нулей на диагонали.

Comment: Да, дописал программу, спасибо, учел нулевой элемент.